# Do all Overcooked 2 players need to buy the DLC or just the host?

Tags: overcooked-2

With *Overcooked 2* added to the Xbox Game Pass, for online multiplayer/co-op, do all players need to purchase the DLC to play together or just the host?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Only the host](https://steamcommunity.com/app/728880/discussions/0/1730963192534849717/#c1730963192546164779) needs the DLC.** Other players with the vanilla base game can join.